# Show an only one dialog to write/set two EditTextPreferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm creating a setting activity with an username and password. I use two editTextPreferences, they display their dialog independently one of the other. 
What I want is to have an only one dialog where I can write the username and the password in different editText but in the same dialog using preferences. Is it possible?

THis is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/settings_server">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/user_"
        android:title="@string/settings_user"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:key="@string/password_"
        android:title="@string/settings_password"/>



   </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible?

You can create your own custom `DialogPreference` that uses a layout that contains two `EditText` widgets.

If you mean "is it possible to do using existing `Preference` classes in the Android SDK?", then no, it is not possible.